# Migrate Octopress 2 theme to Octopress 3 theme

Tags: ruby, themes, jekyll, octopress, static-site

How do you migrate an Octopress 2 theme to Octopress 3?

Octopress 2 uses [classic](https://github.com/octopress/classic-theme) as the default theme while Octopress 3 uses the default Jekyll theme. How do I migrate the Octopress 2 classic theme over to Octopress 3?